# Keras TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: keras

My model is correctly formed:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x:x/255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(160,320,3)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_generator, samples_per_epoch= len(train_samples), validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=len(validation_samples), nb_epoch=3)
```

Note, parenthesis are in place.  However when I fit I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "modell.py", line 70, in <module>
    model.fit(train_generator, samples_per_epoch= len(train_samples), validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=len(validation_samples), nb_epoch=3) 
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

`train_generator` is a 2D array

```
train_generator = generator(train_samples, batch_size=32)
```

I must be blind because I can't spot the problem. Does anyone know why `fit` is looking for an extra argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a generator to train, you must use the method `model.fit_generator`.

The method `fit` will always demand for inputs (X) and outputs/targets (Y)

Comment: I was blind, now I can see : https://youtu.be/SnkjvECEQr4?t=24  It was in the sample code and I just couldn't see it.  Thanks a million!