# Keras LSTM neural net: TypeError: LSTM() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Y'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train a LSTM neural net using Keras (version 2.2.0) and TensorFlow (version 1.1.0). I know that there are more recent TensorFlow versions but unfortunately [I'm having some issues installing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472625/using-anaconda-with-conda-forge-behind-a-corporate-firewall-blocking-amazon-clou). However, I don't believe that my problem is related to the TensorFlow version.

This is how my Keras code looks like:

```
[...] from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LeakyReLU, LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding

def LSTM(X,Y):
    inputDimension = len(X[0])
    inputSize = len(X)
    
    # create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_length=inputDimension,input_dim=inputDimension,output_dim=256))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X,Y,epochs=3,batch_size=64)
    return model
```

Whenever I try to run it, I end up with the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Main.py", line 208, in  lstmModel = ann.LSTM(scaledTrainingX,trainingY)
> File "ann.py", line 158, in LSTM model.add(LSTM(100))
> TypeError: LSTM() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Y'

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375035/keras-typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y) on StackOverflow but the solution suggested there doesn't help because I'm not using a generator to train my network.

Any help to get this network to run would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you show us complete traceback error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `LSTM(X,Y)` in which you create your model is shadowing the Keras LSTM layer. So when you call:

```
model.add(LSTM(100))
```

you're indeed calling the function that you defined. You need to rename this function to something else.

Comment: Oh boy... This is a bit embarrassing but you're completely right. Thank you very much. However, I now get the following message instead: "TypeError: while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'" even though this parameter is not given anywhere.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know why you're getting this error. If you post a new question with the code and the full traceback I might be able to help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your offer. However, I finally managed to update my TensorFlow version to 1.8.0 and the problem seems to be gone.